# Create an SAP Report from a selected row in a datagrid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to create a SAP Crystal report from a single row selected within a datagrid in a c# wpf application. How do I do this?

---

This is the code that populates the datagrid:

```
private void FillDataGrid() 
{ 
    string cmd = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Bookings"; 
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, connect); 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Bookings"); 
    da.Fill(ds, "Bookings"); 
    dtaBookings.DataContext = ds; 
}
```

The report code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument(); 
        report.Load("../../Invoice.rpt"); 
        using (RoseAcresDatabaseEntities db = new RoseAcresDatabaseEntities()) 
            { 
                report.SetDataSource(from c in db.Bookings select new {c.Last_Name, c.First_Names, c.Email_Address, c.Contact_Number... }); 
            } 
        InvoiceReport.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report; 
    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: You need to add additional information about what you have done and usually showing some code where you have problems. Otherwise, I would recommend you to look for a tutorial or some documentation to get you started.

Comment: This is the code that populates the datagrid:
        private void FillDataGrid()
        {
            string cmd = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Bookings";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, connect);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Bookings");
            da.Fill(ds, "Bookings");
            dtaBookings.DataContext = ds;
        }

Comment: The report code:
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
            report.Load("../../Invoice.rpt");
            using (RoseAcresDatabaseEntities db = new RoseAcresDatabaseEntities())
            {
                report.SetDataSource(from c in db.Bookings select new { c.Last_Name, c.First_Names, c.Email_Address, c.Contact_Number...  });
            }
            InvoiceReport.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
        }

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].